# Allow-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP Status 401

Tags: javascript, cors

mi error es el siguiente:

> Failed to load
>   https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Hola?RGAPI-276acd60-2264-4c3e-aa5e-17333c48ab70:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 401.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function onClick() {

 var api = "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/";
 var apiKey = "?RGAPI-276acd60-2264-4c3e-aa5e-17333c48ab70";
 var query = document.getElementById("summoner").value;
 var fullKey = api + query + apiKey;

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', fullKey, true);
 xhr.send();

 xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

 function processRequest(e) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
   var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
  document.getElementById("span").innerText = response.accountId;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>DSFSF</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>


<body>

<h2>API KAPPAEQUISCU</h2>
<h3>Summoner:</h3>

<input type="text" id="summoner">
<input type="submit" onclick="onClick();">

<h3>SummonerID:</h3>
<span id="span">

</span>
<span id="spanDos">

</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. ¿Has buscado de qué trata el [error 401](https://httpstatuses.com/401)?. También revisa la [documentación](https://developer.riotgames.com/getting-started.html) es posible que te falte algo para realizar correctamente la petición.

Comment: He tenido en cuenta todo en la documentación. El caso es que he estado usando un plugin de chrome CORS y me funciona ahí.

Comment: Coloca esto antes del `xhr.send();` --> `xhr.withCredentials = true;` y me avisas si te funciona

Comment: Sigue estando el mismo problema @CamiloVasquez (https://gyazo.com/f90b057574a695c70cf919a66063bf96)

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta en el API, puede que tu dominio no este autorizado para hacer peticiones al API, verifica la configuración CORS en el server

Comment: Mi dominio es localhost @GerardoLopezDueñas

Comment: Vale, pero debes tener en cuenta que si no estas corriendo en el mismo servidor que el API, esta no recibe "localhost" o 127.0.0.1 como dirección de quien hace la petición, recibe tu IP es lo que debes verificar si el server te da permisos a ti de solicitar información.

Comment: Como puedo comprobarlo? @GerardoLopezDueñas y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lamentablemente en eso no se como ayudarte, la configuración de CORS depende del lenguaje/framework en que este hecho el API. Si no tienes acceso a ella deberías preguntar a quien se encargué del backend.

Comment: Simplemente con eso me ha ayudado un montón. Te lo agradezco @GerardoLopezDueñas